# Mounting a sinatra app on rails 3.1 heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to mount the following

https://github.com/cookinfacebook/fb-koala-heroku

Into a brand new Rails 3.1 app using sinatra, but i'm not sure how to do it.

Where would I put this in a Rails app and what would my route be?

Do I have to move the gems from the sinatra apps Gemfile to my facebook apps Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have more reading to do. It looks like from the koala app template that you don't need Rails - and indeed it would likely add a lot more baggage and problems, since usually its Sinatra OR Rails.

Sinatra and Rails both run using the ruby programming language.

I hope that helps.